# Python Crash Course Q8-10

Tags: python

8-9. Magicians: Make a list of magician’s names. Pass the list to a function called `show_magicians()`, which prints the name of each magician in the list.

8-10. Great Magicians: Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9. Write a function called `make_great()` that modifies the list of magicians by adding the phrase `"the Great"` to each magician’s name. Call `show_magicians()` to see that the list has actually been modified.

For 8-10:
I understand that this will work:

```
def make_great(list_of_magicians):
    index = 0
    while index < len(list_of_magicians):
        for magician in list_of_magicians:
            list_of_magicians[index] = "The Great " + magician
            print(list_of_magicians) # Seeing change in list each time.
            index += 1
```

**Q: Why does this not work? **

```
def make_great(list_of_magicians):
    for magician in list_of_magicians:
        magician = 'The great ' + magician
```

Comment: `magician` does not point to the value in the list, but a copy. if you want to modify it directly in the list, you need to index into it.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also see, [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: @FlipTack Sort of. But consider: `a=[['a'],['b'],['c']]` `for u in a:u[0]+='z'` _will_ modify the items in `a`.

Comment: FWIW, I've added a few implementations of `make_great` to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
magician = 'The great ' + magician
```

only modifies the variable `magician`. This has no effect on the values
in the list.

In the code that does work, the corresponding line is:

```
list_of_magicians[index] = "The Great " + magician
```

This changes the actual contents of the list, so it works.

Comment: In other words: ```magician = ...``` assigns something to the variable ```magician``` and ```list_of_magicians[index] = ...``` assigns something to the list item.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for magician in list_of_magicians:
    magician = 'The great ' + magician
```

The first line iterates over the strings in `list_of_magicians` binding each one in turn to the name `magician`. It does *not* create a copy of the string. However, the next line creates a new string by concatenating `'The great '` with the `magician` string and then the `=` binds that new string to the name `magician`, and after that operation that name no longer refers to the list item.

If instead we could do `str_prepend('The great ', magician)` then your technique would work, but we can't do that because Python strings are immutable. But here's a related example using a list of lists. And because lists *are* mutable we can change the lists in `a` by modifying `u`:

```
a=[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
for u in a:
    u.append('z')
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[['a', 'z'], ['b', 'z'], ['c', 'z']]
```

---

Here's one way to write the `make_great` function. In Python, it's generally preferred to iterate directly over the items in a container rather than iterating indirectly via indices. A straight-forward way to write the `make_great` function is to do this:

```
def make_great(list_of_magicians):
    new_list = []
    for magician in list_of_magicians:
        new_list.append('The great ' + magician)
    return new_list

magician_names = ['Alice', 'Alex', 'Blake']
magician_names = make_great(magician_names)
print(magician_names)
```

**output**

```
['The great Alice', 'The great Alex', 'The great Blake']
```

This replaces the original `magician_names` list with a new list. If we wish to modify the original list object we can use slice assignment:

```
magician_names[:] = make_great(magician_names)
```

Alternatively, we can do the slice assignment inside `make_great`, mutating the passed-in list. It's conventional for Python functions that mutate their argument to return `None`.

```
def make_great(list_of_magicians):
    new_list = []
    for magician in list_of_magicians:
        new_list.append('The great ' + magician)
    list_of_magicians[:] = new_list

magician_names = ['Alice', 'Alex', 'Blake']
make_great(magician_names)
print(magician_names)
```

Or we can do virtually the same thing using a list comprehension, which is more compact (and slightly faster), and avoids the need for the `new_list` name:

```
def make_great(list_of_magicians):
    list_of_magicians[:] = [
        'The great ' + magician for magician in list_of_magicians
    ]
```